# Chrome extension that replaces words doesn't work on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I have been trying to figure out the answer to this for around an hour now, and cant find anything. I am creating a Chrome Extension that replaces "hillary clinton" with "Donald trump", and it works on every site except for Facebook. It works with peoples names that show up when you search it, but not for any of the posts. My Code:

```
walk(document.body);

function walk(node) 
{
    var child, next;

    switch ( node.nodeType )  
    {
        case 1:  // Element
        case 9:  // Document
        case 11: // Document fragment
            child = node.firstChild;
            while ( child ) 
            {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child);
                child = next;
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            handleText(node);
            break;
    }
}

function handleText(textNode) 
{
    var v = textNode.nodeValue;
    var z = textNode.nodeValue.nodeValue;

    v = v.replace(/\bHillary Clinton\b/gi, "Donald Trump");
    textNode.nodeValue = v;
}
```

My manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Hillary Trump",
    "description": "CHANGE THIS!!!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*",
                "https://*.facebook.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "content2.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      }
}
```

Comment: perhaps your walk function is being run before the page loads. facebook pages are very dynamic, you'll need to account for this in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry I'm new, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @JaromandaX, so I'd enclose that code in:
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
   // CODE HERE

Comment: perhaps, I haven't looked at exactly how your code would be used with mutation observer, I just recommended mutation observer to observe mutations to the DOM so that you can run your code when the page changes, because the page changes dynamically in facebook as you scroll down the page for example

Comment: Ah, alright, Ill give it a shot :)

Comment: @JaromandaX, this code:
function handleText(textNode) 
{
    var v = textNode.nodeValue;

// create an observer instance
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(target);
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log("Success");
            v = v.replace(/\bTrump\b/gi, "Turnip").replace(/\bDonald Turnip\b/gi, "Ronald Turnip").replace(/\bDonald J. Trump\b/gi, "Ronald D. Turnip");
         textNode.nodeValue = v;
    });    
});
doesnt work :/

Comment: well, you're creating an observer and never using it to observe anything

Answer (score 0):

Use Mutation Observer like this

```
function handleTextnode(textnode) {
    textnode.nodeValue = textnode.nodeValue.replace(/Hillary Clinton/gi, "Donald Trump");
}

function walk(root) {
    var handleChildren = function (node) {
        [].filter.call(node.childNodes, function(child) {
            return child.nodeType == 3;
        }).forEach(handleTextnode);
    }
    handleChildren(root);
    [].forEach.call(root.querySelectorAll('*'), handleChildren);
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type == "childList" && mutation.addedNodes.length) {
            [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, walk);
        }
    });
});
var options = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};
observer.observe(document.body, options);

walk(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'VE CREATED A SIMPLE UPDATE TO MAKE IT WORK**
All you need to do, is encase the whole thing in a setInterval like down below:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  // ADD CODE HERE!!
}
```